# %TYPE for collection's element type

Tags: oracle, plsql

We can use record_name.field% type to reference a field's type...

But if field is a collection (table of ...) the %type is the collection type.

is there a way with %TYPE or something like it to reference the collection **element** type?

```
declare
  type rec1_t is record (
    n1 integer
  );
  type rec1_tab_t is table of rec1_t;

  type rec2_t is record (
    x rec1_tab_t
  );

  x1 rec2_t;
  x2 x1.x%type;
begin
  null;
end;
/
```

So in this case x2 is of type rec1_tab_t.

I want something that given the variables, reference the element's type of rec1_tab_t, i.e., rec1_t. Using something like:

```
declare
  x2 x1.x(1)%type
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get it but  : %rowtype ? http://psoug.org/snippet/TYPE-vs-ROWTYPE--Whats-the-difference_700.htm

Comment: No. I edited the question with more details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Isn't every element in rec1_tab_t going to be an integer? How would you end up with any other data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, AFAIK there is no way to reference a collection's element type in Oracle's PL/SQL.

The usage of `%TYPE` and `%ROWTYPE` attributes is defined in Oracle Database Documentation, book "Database PL/SQL Language Reference" see version 19c here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/index.html